# Adding bootstrap mixin into Rails project. rbenv error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mixins, rbenv

This is a continuation of [rails, bootstrap, media-breakpoint-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061436/rails-bootstrap-media-breakpoint-only/52061737?noredirect=1#comment91090506_52061737) but I don't think one needs to refer back to that.

I have a Rails project in which I am attempting to use the Bootstrap function media-breakpoint-only.

A search of my computer shows that media-breakpoint-only is defined in ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_breakpoints.scss

My ~/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss is

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 * require_tree .
 * require_self
 */

// See 
//  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcBXXOdPfgE&index=8&list=PLYM1n9xxMy4ClO2GjX73U3BLsXx9Z7wh5
$navbar-default-bg: red;

// Shnelvar
//   See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";

// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";

// Shnelvar
//   For ralph-shiny-button etc.
@import "ralph";

// Shnelvar
//   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404154/bootstrap-change-the-navbar-font-size
//   See https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-you-change-the-bootstrap-font-style
.nav a{
    color: white !important;
    // font-size: 3.8em !important;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    }

@import "bootstrap/breakpoints";

// See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/
h1 {
 @include media-breakpoint-only(xs) {
   color: red;
 }
 @include media-breakpoint-only(sm) {
   color: green;
 }
 @include media-breakpoint-only(md) {
   color: blue;
 }
 @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
   color: yellow;
 }
 @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
   color: orange;
 }
}
```

Please note that I have

```
 * require_tree .
 * require_self
```

and not

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

so, I believe, the "requires" are commented out.

When I attempt to load my webpage I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in StaticPages#root

Showing ~/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #15 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/breakpoints.
Load paths:
  ~/app/assets/config
  ~/app/assets/images
  ~/app/assets/javascripts
  ~/app/assets/stylesheets
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.3.3/vendor/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  ~/node_modules
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/fonts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/images
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/popper_js-1.14.3/assets/javascripts
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
  ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.7/assets/stylesheets
```

Apparently, ~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap-4.1.3/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/ isn't in any of the load paths.

I'm thinking I might have an rbenv error but I'm not sure.

My environment is
Rails 5.2.0
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

Please further note that if I get rid of the @import "bootstrap/breakpoints"; and the h1 css that I am able to use a Bootstrap navbar successfully.  Thus, I assume, I have installed bootstrap sucessfully.

Help!!!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117360/using-bootstrap-media-breakpoint-only-in-rails-5-solved for the solution

Answer (score 0):

in gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0’
```

then do file inside the stylesheet assets name it bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap”;
```

This video can help you about how to add bootstrap gem to your ruby on rails app
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxYsMacHHtU&t=122s